# Where should I put a second page?

Tags: web-services, web, apache2, http-status-code-404, putty

I got 2 html pages. I put my first html page inside of my document root (var/www) in apache 2 and it works. it has a button which moves secondpage. When I enter my ip on browser, I see first page I press login but 404 error comes in. Where should I locate my secondpage?

Here is my code

```
<html>
<h1>Welcome to e-flea market!</h1>
<table align="center" width="40%" height="88" bgcolor="rgb(21, 232, 246)">
<tr>

<td align="left" width="50">
<p align="left">
<font color="#ffffff" size="3">
Your name:<br>
</font>
<input type="text"><br>
<font color="#9DACCB" size="5">
</font>
</p>
</td>

<td align="left" width="100">
<p align="left">
<br>
<form method="get" action="\Users\Hp\.atom\2ndpage.html" >
<input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 2ndpage.html is in the same directory as your first page, you could update your form to be:

```
<form method="get" action="2ndpage.html" >
```